# pasport-ldap not working with latest package

Tags: node.js, ldap

This is a working code with older passport-LDAP package but after up-gradation of the package to the latest version it's not working am getting output as unauthorised.

Can anyone help me what's changed with LDAP or what am doing wrong with the piece of code.
In the code, I have not given ------ for the links and some other values

```
var express = require('express'),
passport = require('passport'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
var OPTS = {
server: {
url: "ldaps://--------------"
bindDn: 'ZGN',
bindCredentials: 'password',
searchBase: 'DC=---------,DC=-----',
searchFilter: '(samaccountName={{username}})',
searchAttributes: ["displayName", "givenName", "mail", "title", "telephoneNumber", "samaccountname", "userPrincipalName"],
}
// ,
// usernameField: 'username',
// passwordField: 'password'
};

var app = express();

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
res.send({status: 'ok'});
});
//API call with parameter
// {
// "username":"coreid",
// "password":"password"
// }

app.listen(8080);
```